# How do I update an array of labels

Tags: c#, wpf, label

This sounds wierd but i have no idea how to do this, despite the fact i've read lots of articles and answers about it.
this one seems to be the most clear, but unfortunately it doesn't help me.

[Like this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1047/wpf-tutorial-forcing-a-binding-update)

so i have an array of labels that should be updated during the for cycles:

```
public const int NUM_OF_PAGES = 128;
...
    int[] PEcnt = new int[NUM_OF_PAGES];
    Label[] PElabels = new Label[NUM_OF_PAGES]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PAGES; i++) // initialization
    {
        PEcnt[i] = 0;
        PElabels[i] = new Label();
        PElabels[i].Content = 0;
        PElabels[i].Margin = new Thickness(50 + 80 * (i % 16), 50 + 20 * (i / 16), 0, 0);
        Grid1.Children.Add(PElabels[i]);
}
...
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PAGES; i++)
{
    PEcnt[i] += 2;
    PElabels[i].Content = PEcnt[i];
    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(PElabels[i], Label.ContentProperty).UpdateTarget(); //trying to update
}
```

but this throws me "System.NullReferenceException"

hope u will help me, learning is difficult, but im trying hard

Comment: You try to `GetBindingExpressionBase` for `ContentProperty` but you create no such binding so you get null, hence the error. Why do you even need to do that?

Comment: well, ok. and what shpuld i do?
i'm making a very simplified model of memory card and there i think should be shown how many times we were adressed to each page

Comment: Remove this line. Updating `Content` should be enough to update `Label`

Comment: But how to update content?

Comment: You already do it in `PElabels[i].Content = PEcnt[i];`

Comment: Yes but nothing updates on my window, and as i understand i need to update (refresh) the window or labels to see what is happening.
i need to see how labels are changing while for cycle is running

Answer (score 0):

don't .UpdateTarget(); and it should be okay I believe

you don't need to get binding expressions for this, if you are using it else where do not update target here.

Comment: without .UpdateTarget(); i have no error as well as no update happens.
i don't use binding expressions anywhere alse, then what should i use?

Comment: what are you expecting ? I can see all labels filled with data, what is your expectation

Comment: an array of 128 items all with text 2 in them as initial text was 0 and then you add 2 to it

Comment: it happens in "for" cycle and after all ill add random generator.. its hard to explain what i really have to do

Comment: well code is exactly doing what it is suppoised to do, it creates 128 labels and sets content 2 into it.... let us know if you need further help

Comment: Yes but nothing updates on my window, and as i understand i need to update (refresh) the window or labels to see what is happening. i need to see how labels are changing while for cycle is running

Comment: are you expecting to see numbers changing dynamically ?

Comment: well you should then have to go on a different thread to update the value and release the UI Thread to update itself...

Answer (score -1):

so first of all:
The *Label.Content* Property stores an object! So you can store an *Integer* in it without casting!

You are trying to update an *BindingExpression* on an **NOTbinded** Property!

So the way you should solve your problem, is by just **NOT** updating it.
Because your Label isn't using any bindings your called function returns *null*.

So just Store your *Integer* in the content property and YOLO. Here is the working code:

```
public const int NUM_OF_PAGES = 128;
Label[] PElabels = new Label[NUM_OF_PAGES];

...

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PAGES; i++) // initialization
{
    PElabels[i] = new Label();

    PElabels[i].Content = 0; //Storing your Data as int in object

    PElabels[i].Margin = new Thickness(50 + 80 * (i % 16), 50 + 20 * (i / 16), 0, 0);
    Grid1.Children.Add(PElabels[i]);
}

...


for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PAGES; i++)
{
    PElabels[i].Content = (int)PElabels[i].Content + 2; //Storing your new Data
}
```

**SO!!!!**
If you realy need to use this update binding, you have to set your content property to an Binding. To do so, you have to store your data in some property for example in the Label.DataContext. Now you need to set the Binding (pointing at the DataContext) to you Label.ContentProperty. After doing that you can update your **BindingExpression** and the Label will change.

Working Code here:

```
public const int NUM_OF_PAGES = 128;
Label[] PElabels = new Label[NUM_OF_PAGES];

...

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PAGES; i++) // initialization
{
    PEcnt[i] = 0;
    PElabels[i] = new Label();

    PElabels[i].DataContext = 0; //Storing your Data
    Binding PEcntBind = new Binding("DataContext");
    PEcntBind.Source = PElabels[i];
    PElabels[i].SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, PEcntBind); //Binding to your stored Data

    PElabels[i].Margin = new Thickness(50 + 80 * (i % 16), 50 + 20 * (i / 16), 0, 0);
    Grid1.Children.Add(PElabels[i]);
}

...

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PAGES; i++)
{
    PEcnt[i] += 2;
    PElabels[i].DataContext = PEcnt[i]; //Storing your new Data

    BindingExpression LabBindEx = (PElabels[i] as FrameworkElement).GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty);
    LabBindEx.UpdateTarget(); //Updating the Bindings
}
```

*(Oh and by the way you have to use GetBindingExpression not GetBindingExpressionBase)*

Comment: why you need .. BindingExpression LabBindEx = (PElabels[i] as FrameworkElement).GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty);
    LabBindEx.UpdateTarget(); //Updating the Bindings
  ????

Comment: You don't, but it was the main part of his question. So I explained it. Because maybe he is working on a lot bigger program in witch case he needs to update it like that and the Question code only is an example.